# Is Physics SE a good place to ask for textbook references?

Tags: discussion, scope, resource-recommendation

I sponsor a high school astronomy club. Most of my students have completed AP<sup>1</sup> Calculus BC and are ready for a calculus-based discussion of astronomical physics. I am searching for a source-book to use for discussions at club meetings. Is Physics.SE a good place to ask "What is an overview of appropriate texts for this purpose?"

---

<sup>1</sup> These are advanced college placement exams for high school students in the US and a few other places.

Comment: That said, that question looks about appropriate for this site, as long as your read carefully [the guidelines for resource-recommendation questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39452/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-is-physics-se-a-good-place-to-ask-for-textbook).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this *would* be a very good fit for our [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag... if this question didn't already exist:

- [What are good books for graduates/undergraduates in Astrophysics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44882/what-are-good-books-for-graduates-undergraduates-in-astrophysics)

That question is very general, so you can browse through the list of resources recommended there and pick out the ones that are at an appropriate level. Thus I don't see a need for a separate question that duplicates a subset of the existing one.